# Prove that for any positve real

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Prove that for any positive real numbers $x,y,z$ such that $xyz \geq 1$

$$\frac{x^5-x^2}{x^5+y^2+z^2} + \frac{y^5-y^2}{y^5+z^2+x^2} +\frac{z^5-z^2}{z^5+x^2+y^2} \geq 0.$$

This problem is from the $2005$ IMO competition.

Comment: For any number $x$ such that $x\geq1$, $x^{5}\geq x^{2}$.

Comment: @All I have edited the question as I believe the original edit to be in error

Comment: This question is from an IMO. It doesn't seem necessary to give partial progress as we can expect the question to be quite difficult/tricky. I think this question should remain open so that people can demonstrate other techniques.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt I agree with you! However my reputation is less than 3k, I can't cast re-opening votes just yet.

Answer (score 6):

Since,$$\frac{x^5-x^2}{x^5+y^2+z^2} - \frac{x^5-x^2}{x^3(x^2+y^2+z^2)} = \frac{x^2(x^3-1)^2(y^2+z^2)}{x^3(x^2+y^2+z^2)(x^5+y^2+z^2)} \ge 0$$

Hence, it suffices to prove $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{x^5-x^2}{x^3(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \ge 0$

$$\sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{x^5-x^2}{x^3(x^2+y^2+z^2)} = \frac{\sum\limits_{cyc} \left(x^2 - \frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \ge \frac{\sum\limits_{cyc} \left(x^2 - yz\right)}{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \frac{\sum\limits_{cyc} \left(x-y\right)^2}{2(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \ge 0$$

Since, $xyz \ge 1$.

[Here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=281573&sid=c69cf9f284ed3d82b7c82f0a6c2aeef3#p281573) are a few more proofs of the inequality, possibly neater.